# How to search a Google Sheets by specific string?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I have a Google Sheets script (Google Apps Script) that fetches referrals. Currently this is my code (it works)

```
function getReferralNames() {
  const app = SpreadsheetApp;
  const wb = app.openById('1gWpROx-dmOoanhhPrK3dDYsWbp9z3BLt5nLNZGKU');
  const ss = wb.getSheetByName('Web App Database');
  const data = ss.getRange('A1').getDataRegion().getValues();
  const refNames = data.map(val => `${val[3]}`);
  const referralNames = data.map(val => `<option>${val[0]}</option>`);
  referralNames.splice(0,2);

  return referralNames;
}
```

What I want it to do, is fetch a referral by a specific name instead of ALL referrals. Here is a picture of the sheet, I want it to only show referrals for the specific user logged in. ("Referral By" is the column I want to see if its the same name as the user's name, and only show that row)

[image: The Google Sheet]

I was thinking of doing an if statement with .indexOf() but I still cannot figure it out, and need some snippets or help from you guys <3

Comment: Take all values from the column, and then do a for loop across all values to check if the value == the name you're looking for. Something like ` var referredByColumn = sheet.getRange('E3:E20'); var values = range.getValues(); for (var j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
        if (values[j][0] == targetName) {
          // do something
        }
      }`

Comment: You could use textFinder

Comment: @Sciffany thank you so much, that worked! I'll answer this question myself with the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Sciffany, but here is the working code.

```
  var referredByColumn = ss.getRange("E3:E20");
  var values = referredByColumn.getValues();
  var referralNames = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
    if (values[j] == "Barry Wernick") {
      //Logger.log (values[j]);
      referralNames.push("<option>" + values[j] + "</option>");
    }
  }
```

Just just debug code, but it's the answer to the question at least.

Comment: You could add a `ui.prompt` so that you can enter the name from a dialog